# "Publish JUnit test result report" Jenkins plugin not supporting JTL file XML format generated by jmeter command -J and -l options

Tags: jenkins, ant, jmeter

I am generating Jmeter output JTL file in XML format using below command:

```
sh jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t /User/sudhir.tataraju/Desktop/Automation/test.jmx -l  /root/.jenkins/workspace/JmeterTest/Output_test.xml
```

Same `Output_test.xml` file am using for Jenkins job plugin  *"Publish JUnit test result report"*

But report is not generating throwing error in Console Output log of jmeter job as

```
Recording test results
None of the test reports contained any result
```

I found issue is because of Output_test.xml format, seems the plugin is only for XML formatted JTL file generated by ANT application.

If I use the XML formatted JTL file generated by ANT application then my plugin working showing the failed test cases report.

Please suggest either:

- any way to convert my non-supported XML to ANT-formatted XML that *"Publish JUnit test result report"* plugin supports; or
- an alternate plugin that supports normal XML generated by my above-mentioned jmeter command (which should display's similar output highlighting all failed test cases and its reasons without need of ANT application).

Comment: Use this plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin

Comment: I tried with performance plugin issue is its trying to install jmeter-5.0.zip
 my jmx file created with jmeter 2.11, so jmeter 5 not supporting my jmx.

Comment: jmeter 2.11 is 9 versions old which is huge (hundreds of bugs fixed and hundreds of improvements). Upgrade your jmeter to 5.0 by reading release notes

Answer (score 1):

The JTL file generated by JMeter is a specific format that has no relation with JUnit test result xml.

This is why it does not work.

You can use [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) that understands many JMeter formats:

- Summariser
- JMeter CSV output format
- JMeter XML output format

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

Although the format of the jtl file is xml that xml format is not supported by the "**Publish JUnit test result report**" plugin.

you need to convert the xml formatted jtl file into xml which is readable by "**Publish JUnit test result report**" plugin.

which can be done using below command.

**java -jar /opt/m2u.jar --input /opt/merged.jtl --output /opt/JunitReport.xml**

m2u.jar is open source jar, can be googled or download from my link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-o8guOgMS6LziahMDuFMXliqXcq5zN0i/view?usp=sharing

Note: The output JunitReport.xml should be placed in workspace folder for plugin to recognize.